# Do I need to open a bank account from my local branch?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking

I can recall on several occasions when asked to give bank details that I had to give the address of my bank. I always put the address of my local branch where I opened the account and which I normally used.

I'm going to be opening a new account with a different bank. One which does not have a branch in my small town. It does however have a branch in the nearby city which is what I will be using normally.

I'm going to be in a different city tomorrow however and I'm wondering, if I open the account there will this account be registered with that city b branch?
Will this in anyway affect what can be done with the account, assuming that visiting the city b branch is usually very awkward for me?

Comment: Country ? Country ? Country ?

Comment: The account will have the bank address of the branch where you opened it and not the branch nearest to your home. While opening query whether this can be done. And why are you worried if your account can be serviced in a different branch or not. I have never visited the branch where I opened my bank account and whenever required, I go to the nearest branch.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that in UK retail banking, this **used to matter** but nowadays, as a general rule, **does not usually matter any more**.

> if I open the account there will this account be registered with that city b branch?

Yes.

> Will this in anyway affect what can be done with the account, assuming that visiting the city b branch is usually very awkward for me?

Never in nearly thirty years of being a UK retail banking customer has it mattered which branch my account was held at. The days of one's *own* 'bank manager' being someone to have a personal relationship with are long gone - these days it's all algorithms and 'personal account care consultants', or whatever grim corporate-speak your particular bank uses.

As an extreme example, all customers of First Direct have the *same* branch address, since it is an online-only subsidiary of HSBC.

For (mutual) building society's banking operations things *might* be different, but I don't think so.

---

I will finish with a caveat: the one exception I know of. In 2013, when [Lloyds Banking Group was forced to divest a chunk of its retail banking operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyds_Bank#Divestment_and_return_to_Lloyds_Bank), a number of customers who had opened accounts with a branch of Lloyds Bank (*before* it became Lloyds TSB) found that, as part of the divestiture, they were going to become customers of the (newly-resurrected) TSB Bank, rather than remaining with the portion that reverted to being Lloyds Bank. The division was made on sort codes, which ultimately come down to the branch the account was opened at.

Not sure anyone cared though.

Comment: "Not sure anyone cared though." afaict if your local branch and the branch your account was based at were on opposite sides of the split you were faced with a reduction of services at your local branch.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Nationwide Building Society don't care either.  I opened an account as a student.  The branch has never changed since then, even though I've now moved to a different county.